# Collect values in a certain range from a binary tree?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

for example{Range:4,6} would return [4,5,5,6] here:

[image]

Comment: Depends on how the binary tree is implemented. Show us the definition of the tree, please

Comment: First of all, that's specifically a binary search tree (BST), not any old binary tree. Secondly, without knowing the implementation of the BST, I can't give you better than pseudocode. Is your BST implemented as a nested list, or nested dict, or a custom class, or...? So I'll ask again, please edit the definition of your BST into your original post

Comment: @Oliver. Do you have code that represents the tree?

Comment: Well articulated, @gnibbler.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, well clearly I can't type as fast as you :)

Comment: @gnibbler: no, seriously... You expressed in half a line, what I fumbled around with for a paragraph

Comment: So please edit your post to include the code for that class

Comment: Clearly, I'm not communicating as well I should be. When I asked you to post the code for that class, I meant all the code starting from `class BinarySearchTree`, all the way until the class definition is finished

Comment: Did you write this custom class yourself? What you have is not yet a class definition

Comment: Where is `EmptyValue` defined?

Comment: `Above it` does not help. We need to know what we're dealing with here. Please make a __fully self-contained__ post so that we can understand what you're trying to do. Also, there is no way that a variable can take the value `pass`, so saying `it's just pass` doesn't help either. Please make our lives less difficult in our attempts to help you. Otherwise, we just might mistake you for a troll and give up altogether

Comment: I can understand that, but we don't know the context of your question. So you need to really give us something that we can understand having not seen any of the stuff that you've presumably been looking at for the past little while, as those are not implicitly understood, to us

Comment: Note that [binary __search__ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Difference_between_binary_tree_and_binary_search_tree) don't allow duplicates. Allowing duplicates prevents you from _searching_ for the lowerbound in log(n) time. With your tree it appears you are forced to scan the entire tree unless there are extra constraints you haven't told us about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def allInRange(bst, left, right):
    if bst is EmptyValue:
        return
    if left <= bst.root <= right:
        print(bst.root)
    allInRange(bst.left, left, right)
    allInRange(bst.right, left, right)
```

Comment: @Oliver: yes, and you'd have to change the `print(bst.root)` line to include a return and an accumulator

Comment: @Oliver: changing the last two lines to returns should be part of the previously mentioned accumulator

Comment: @Oliver: why don't you make an attempt, and see where it goes. If you can't figure it out, make a post - we'll be here to help you out